# Mac OS X Yosemite Java 1.6 Downgrade to 1.6u35

Tags: macos, java

I installed the latest version of Java 1.6 provided by Apple and didn't realize that the application I have to do development for must use 1.6 update 35. Is there anyway I can uninstall the latest version and downgrade to 1.6 update 35? I think what I need is Java for OS X 2013-005 instead of Java for OS X 2014-001. The 2013-005 version won't let me install it now since a more current version is already installed.

Comment: What exactly does the new version break? It deals with security holes in the older version

Comment: Its a bug in liferay that if you generated a LAR with a certain version of Java 1.6, then you have to use that same version to redeploy it otherwise it fails. I found the solution though and will post it in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides developer packages at http://developer.apple.com/downloads and downloading Java For OS X 2012-005 is the version I need (update 35) through the developer site allows it to install even if a newer version of Java 1.6 is already installed. It installs to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines which looks like the same place that Java 7 and Java 8 are installed to as well. They have all the other update versions out there too.